# EntityFramework DataAnnotations validation doesnt work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

I've used EF Power Tools to auto generate my models from an existing database.  Im using DataAnnotations to perform required validation, which works for most part except when validating properties that have foreign key relationship with other tables (one to many, etc..).  What do I need to do in order to accomplish the validation of these properties?

In the below code, I'm trying to make DistributorId property a required field.

```
 public class Event
{
    public Event()


    public int EventId { get; set; }
    [Remote ("CheckDuplicateEventName","Event",AdditionalFields="InsertMode")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Event Name is required.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Distributor is required.")]
    public int DistributorId { get; set; }

    public virtual Distributor Distributor { get; set; }

}
```

Mapping class

```
 public EventMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.EventId);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(256);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Events");
        this.Property(t => t.EventId).HasColumnName("EventId");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        this.Property(t => t.DistributorId).HasColumnName("DistributorId");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Distributor)
            .WithMany(t => t.Events)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.DistributorId);


    }
```

Tnx!

Comment: Are you wanting to verify that the related record exists?  I don't think you can do that, you have to rely on the database to do that for you.

Comment: I'm just trying to validate DistributorId as a Required field on my form.  The validation for DistributorId never kicks off, as opposed to Name, where it works fine.

Comment: Yea, I don't think you can do that with a data annotation because EF doesn't treat the relationship id fields the same as normal database fields.  Alternatively, you can override the `SaveChanges` method on your data context and do the validation yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This is very simply because `Name` is a `string` (which is nullable), while `DistributorId` is an `int` (not nullable). That means that `DistributorId` always exists (although can be not the value you looking for, but still `[Required]` validation is satisfied.

What you probably want to change is to

- either replace `[Required]` with something that will validate the actual value `[Range]` is great example here.
- or have `DistributorId` as string converting it to int before writing to the database.

Hope this helps

Comment: That, or for some very basic validation, do some kind of range validation on the int value.